# Jquery 'or' statement?

Tags: jquery, keycode

I would like for a text box to disappear if a person clicks out side of it (.focusout or .blur) but I also want to be able do the same function if Esc is pressed (key 27). I am not sure how to get both to be recognized without ruining my entire script.

Comment: please post what you have tried till now. some code that does the focusout and blur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind both events to the same function with

```
$(selector).bind("blur keyup",function(e){...})
```

And then it's just decision logic to see if it was a key that was pressed or whatnot.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
$('#selector').bind('blur keyup', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 27 || e.keyCode == undefined)
        $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom event bound to the text box:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#id").bind("blur keyup myCustomEvent"),function(event){
    //whatever you need
    // you can trigger this logic again via .trigger("myCustomEvent");
    });

});
</script>
```